# Deploying a Java web application to Amazon

Tags: java, mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am sure this question has been asked and answered before multiple times. But unfortunately, I am still not clear. Here is my issue.

I have a JSP, Servlet application which uses MySQL as the database. I have built the WAR file as well. Now I am in need of deploying this so it can be accessed online by anyone.

I looked into lot of areas including normal web hosting. However even though the services like DailyReazor are highly secured, they provide little for MySQL, around 250 MB for the package I selected.

Now I am looking into Amazon AWS. In AWS I am expecting to deploy my aplication and make it available online.The MySQL server should not contain limits like 250MB.

But I have never ever used this service AWS before. By reading various posts, I know that `Elastic Beanstalk` is the easiest way to go, but still not convinced about how to deploy it properly with database access and all. And in the other hand, will they give me a web address like "www.example.com" or will they simply provide an IP address?? I am also familiar with tomcat so I need to use it.

We will not upload files (images etc) at the moment, so I believe we can manage with around 20$ per month?

I really appreciate if someone can provide a clear guidance on deploying java web applications in Amazon, with the requirements I mentioned about MySQL, Global access and so on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Amazon RDS for MySQL](http://aws.amazon.com/rds/mysql/) is a Database-as-a-service offerring from AWS.  It is scaleable up to 3TB, and has scaleable IO as well.  Of course it also depends on how much you prepared to pay. they manage the DB for you (backup etc).  You get a URL to connect, credentials and you are set to go.

Amazon Elastic Beanstalk uses Tomcat. So you should be familiar with that.  You upload your WAR file and specify what EC2 flavor you want (CPU/MEM etc).  They launch a VM that is configured with Jva and Tomcat and deploy the WAR for you.  You get an IP address.

[Amazon Route 53](http://aws.amazon.com/route53/) is the DNS service, where you can assign the IP address to your domain (assuming you have one)

Comment: I am in the process of calculating the price at the moment. Here is the link - https://calculator.s3.amazonaws.com/index.html. When I calculate the price, it gives me heavy stuff like $100 ! Maybe I added invalid data....

Comment: `You get an IP address` - I need a web URL.

Comment: That is what the DNS service is for.  Do you have a domain?

Comment: Regarding pricing, you sohuld start with the smallest EC2 size (xs) I think it falls into the free tier they offer. If you want just one machine and knows your way around Linux, you can opt to use EC2 alone (without beanstalk) and that could lower the price

Comment: instead of Amazon RDS, you could, of course, install MySQL on your own. It does require technical skill, like basic know how of Linux, and reading through the MySQL installation and configuration docs

Comment: Of course I do have a linux machine and I know how to install it. But, will it work? I mean, this is a commercial startup product, will it simply fail bcs of this method?

Comment: asking "will it work" in general, will not provide you with any better answer than "yes".  I have given you guidelines as close as I can to your question. be more specific and you will get more specific info

Comment: regarding the funds, what I meant is monthly pay. Monthly more than 100 USD is too much. Regarding the URL, I will purchase one from Go Daddy. But, how to bind this with the IP given by amazon?

Comment: take a look at AWS Route 53 documentation. ask if there is something you don't understand.

Comment: I am guessing much of the asking price is for AWS RDS (the MySQL service) you can try and install MySQL yourself, or simply start with smallest/cheapest instance

Comment: Regarding the EC2 instance, I considered the micro instance. For DB, I considered db.ts.small. My application will have nearly 5000 requests per day (every time it will connect to DB) for the first year. Any ideas about the performnce?

Comment: 5000 requests per day is ~3.5 req per minute, or one request every 15 seconds.  doesn't sound too demanding to me.